# Get Laravel 4 URL parameters.

Tags: laravel-4

Is there an easier way to get and URL parameters similar to that when appending pagination?

```
<a href="url('user/report', $parameters = Input::all(), $secure = null);">Link</a>
```

Instead of going `@if(Input::has('param1') Input::get('param1') @endif`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can always default to something if the parameter is missing

```
{{ Input::get('param1', 'default value') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually couldn't find a solution to this after researching (I'm sure there is a way, but couldn't find it) so I just decided to create a quick function, a little arbitrary, but works...

```
$url = '?';

foreach(Input::all() as $input => $value)
    $url .= $input . '=' . $value . '&';

<a href="{{ $url }}param2={{ $var }}">Link</a>
```